# Select SUM of points group by Team Name

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have structured my database like this:

> Username | Team | Points

I want to create an SQL query which will show me 5 sum of total points from all teams which will have most points.

Should I use the `SUM` and `GROUP BY` with `LIMIT 5`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are correct.

You need to `Group by` Team and `Sum` the `points` of each `Team` and use it in `Order by` with descending order. Finally limit first five rows

```
Select Team ,sum(Points) as team_sum
from yourtable
Group by Team 
Order by team_sum desc
Limit 5
```